# UINavigationController - Run Code Before Popping View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a stack of `UIViewController` subclasses. Each modifies a `NSManagedObject` model. Many of them also present their own modal view controllers.

I need to save changes to the `NSManagedObjectContext` when a user either 'pops' the view controller or pushes the next view controller.

Currently, I'm hiding the default back button and setting my own `UIBarButtonItem` with a `target` of `self` and a custom `action`.

This works okay, but ideally, I want to use the default back button and run code before the pop. Is there a way I can run my own code before the pop?

(I'd prefer not to put code into `viewWillDisappear` as persisting to disk can be expensive and this method can also be triggered by modals being displayed by view controller.) Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in `viewDidDisappear`, after checking that `self` is either 1) the *second* last element in `self.navigationController.viewControllers` (the case where the next VC just got pushed) or 2) `self.navigationController` is `nil` (the `self` VC just got popped).

Comment: So you're saying that `self.navigationController` is set to `nil` before `viewDidDisappear` is called (in the event of a pop)? Is it safe to assume this will remain true in future editions of iOS, though...? Is this documented somewhere by Apple?

Comment: I don't know if it's documented, but the behavior has been like that for a long time. You can check two cases just to be safe: `self.navigationController == nil || self is not in self.navigationController.viewControllers`

Comment: Well, Apple docs allude to this at least: `This method removes the top view controller from the stack and makes the new top of the stack the active view controller. If the view controller at the top of the stack is the root view controller, this method does nothing. In other words, you cannot pop the last item on the stack.`

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. This seems like the best there is.

Comment: For pop check isMovingFromParent in viewWillDisappear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.. Navigation controller has a delegate which indicates when a view controller popped or pushed.. You can use that to do your task...

Comment: Actually, I don't believe this is the case or at least I'm not seeing it... here's the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html I too expected it here, but it only has methods for **showing** view controllers... :/

Comment: Yes.. Using these methods you can check which view controller is getting showed.
E.g: A shows B and then B shows C
Now when C is popped, delegate method (willShowViewController) will be called telling B is getting showed.
At this time if topViewController is A, then B is getting Pushed,
and if topViewController is C, then B is becoming visible because C is getting popped.

Comment: I see what you're getting at, and I can see how one might implement it, but I think checking if `self.navigationController == nil` is the easiest and best solution in my case. Still, +1 for the suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add following method in your code:

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use viewWillDissappear to make any changes persistant. 
If required i Use viewWillAppear to recoginze any changes (reload the data) that may have taken place while other puhed view controlers did their work.

Answer (score 0):

For pop check isMovingFromParent in viewWillDisappear

```
func viewWillDisappear(_ animation:Bool){
    super.viewWillDisappear(animation);
    if isMovingFromParent {
        // your code here
    }
}
```